# Setting / Editting the current FacebookWebContext AccessToken

Tags: asp.net, facebook-c#-sdk, facebook-authentication

I'm coding an ASP.NET website that works with facebook.
To make my own life easier, I've decided to work with the facebook C# SDK.

At this point, I've already obtained a valid access token, thus I've authorised correctly. 
(I have done this through server-side C# code, not via the JavaScript SDK)[image]

I now want to store this access token in the current `FacebookWebContext`, so that I can use it through the whole website.

However, when I try to write the value in `FacebookWebContext.Current.AccessToken`, I get the following error:

`Property or indexer FacebookWebContext.Current.AccessToken cannot be assigned to -- it is read only`

Now, I could try to create a new FacebookWebContext, and set this one as the current one, but the constructor doesn't accept an access token.

**How do I put my access token in the current facebook web context?**

Answer (score 0):

It should already have the value when you do : `FacebookWebContext.Current.AccessToken`

Is it empty?